# Align all the fields in a line after applying word-break prop in css

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `spans` inside a `div`:
html:

```
<div class="main">
<span class="title"> Name</span>
<span class="values">/sys/fs/cgroup/sys/fs/</span>
</div>
```

here is how it looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/tdrgz1yj/
as you can see the `size` and `volume` title getting pushed down when I have long text for Name field. Also I cannot increase the width any more cause in actual app, the Volume field goes out of focus.
Is there a way I can align the Name, Size and Volume  fields all in one line even after applying the word-break prop?
Can I make it look something like with css?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `.main { vertical-align: top; }` and done …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just add `display: flex` to the `.parent`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tdrgz1yj/1/)

If you want to move the long text to the same line with the "Name" title, set `display: flex` to the `.main` as well.

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tdrgz1yj/2/)

I suggest using span only to wrap inline elements. Instead, use divs :

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.main {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.values {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">Name:</div>
    <div class="values">/sys/fs/cgroup/sys/fs//sys/fs/cgroup/sys/fs//sys/fs/cgroup/sys/fs/</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">Size:</div>
    <div class="values">223k</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">Volume:</div>
    <div class="values">111</div>
  </div>
</div>
```